# How to directly access Azure On-Prem Data Gateway through code

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, api-gateway

I have set up an Azure On-Premise Data Gateway by following these instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway). I also tested accessing through Logic Apps following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install).

However, I don't want to use Logic Apps. Are there any client libraries where I can directly access the gateway instead of only being able to talk through the Logic Apps workflow schema?

All I'm trying to do is stream files from file paths on-prem using `C#`.

Comment: If the c# is on prem, why do you need the Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unfortunately, there is **no*** such DotNet SDK or any another SDK is available for you as of now which might help in On-Prem Data GateWay accessing.

As of now, you can use only the **[Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem), [Microsoft Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/gateway-reference), [Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install), and [PowerApps services](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/on-premise-apis/)** that may help you to securely transfer the data between *On-Prem and Cloud*.

There is also some list of an available data source for on-prem data gateway. You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem#list-of-available-data-source-types)

If you are trying to move **on-Prem SQL server to Azure SQL Database** then [ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/move-sql-azure-adf) would be helpful

**So finally, you would need to continue with your Logic Apps or other services which currently support the onPrem Data Gateway**

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I don't understand that line of reasoning. If the Logic App itself uses the gateway, then the Logic App itself is an attack surface.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft it doesn't matter who controls things; an attack surface is an attack surface regardless. You shouldn't have mentioned that line of thought at all as it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The gateway is built on top of [Azure Relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-what-is-it), which you can use directly.  Hybrid connections are also available in [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).